# How to get 'correct' default launcher programmatically? Shortcuts lose their title

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-package-managers

**What have I done so far:**

I am currenctly facing some problems with the launchers.
My application **adds shortcuts** to the workspace of the launcher (homescreen).
But on some devices (Samsum Duos) for example, the titles and /or icons
are **changed back after reboot** to my default application one.

So I am currently going through 1000s of lines code in the android 
source to identify the problem, but was not able to find it.

I saw in [InstallShortcutReceiver](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/InstallShortcutReceiver.java?autodive=0%2F)
a comment in line **183** that the "name" provided by `Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME` can in 
some situations be used only for comparison etc and will be replaced
with the applications default name.

> ```
>     // This name is only used for comparisons and notifications, so fall back to activity name
>     // if not supplied
> ```

But (my Samsum Duos is rooted) I could find the complete information's
about the cell position and shortcutInfo's inside of the **launcher.db**.

So it was **not** gone, after reboot, but maybe only not correct *initialized*!

1. **First Question:**

Does anybody know the reason for a custom, programmatically created shortcut to change the title and or icon back to the application's one that created it?

**Next story:**

I noticed that this issue was reproducible on my Samsum Duos, so I decided
to exclude the Devices Launcher from my "save launcher" list.

To receive the default launcher I am doing the following:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = null;
    try {
        resolveInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY); //can return null!
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        ExceptionHandler.logAndSendException(e);//package manager has died
        return false;
    }
```

But the problem now is, that it always returns that the default launchers
package is: `com.android.launcher2.Launcher`, which would be the standard
android stock launcher. But I know that Samsum uses the **TouchWiz home**
launcher, whos Package is located under **com.sec.android.app.launcher**!
That is also where I found the launcher.db and all its ShortcutInfo's.

**2. Second Question**

How do I get reproducible  the *correct* default launcher package to identify
which launcher is used?

**edit:**

I kind of *fixed* the second problem. Somehow the **ResolveInfo** I get from 
the PackageManager seems to be **not reliable**.

For the Samsum Duos I get:

```
resolveInfo.activityInfo.name = com.android.launcher2.Launcher
resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName = com.sec.android.app.launcher //this is what I need
```

But for the Redmi MIUI:

```
  resolveInfo.activityInfo.name = com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher //this time I would need this
  resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName = com.miui.home //the packageName is not complete!
```

I need an unique identifier for the launcher! So I thought *activityInfo.name* would be the
way to go, but it isn't in some situations. And the packageManager seems to apply to too many devices. Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Comment: I kind of fixed the second issue (see my edit), but there is still a problem and I would be glad to figure out the root cause :)